# Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

The modal javascript plugin is working fine. I had a question regarding the library itself.

If you notice in this link

```
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals
// click on LAUNCH DEMO MODAL
```

The modal drop from the top of the screen into the vertical center of the screen. Is this functionality provided in the plugin or is it javascript that I will have to write myself ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `fade` class to the modal in order to get this transition.

Your html should then look something like

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header"></div>
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer"></div>
</div>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch Modal</a>
```

Check it out in action on JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A5y8V/)

From the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals):

> Heads up! If you want your modal to animate in and out, just add a
>   .fade class to the .modal element (refer to the demo to see this in
>   action) and include bootstrap-transition.js.

Comment: Right thanks ! For some reason, I missed that note ! Works great now.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, the functionality is provided in the plugin:

> If you want your modal to animate in and out, just add a .fade class to the .modal element (refer to the demo to see this in action) and include bootstrap-transition.js.